# Link between extended sitting and weak quads

Tags: injury, sports, sitting

Is there any evidence to show that there is a link between extended periods of sitting, I have a 9 to 5 desk job plus 1hr 45 min commute, and the risk of quad tears?

If not, is/are there common factors associated with the increased likelihood of sustaining a quad injury?

Thanks.

Comment: I would expect quad injuries to mainly only happen to people involved in strenuous sports or jobs. Are you asking about people with sedentary jobs who then go out and participate in sports, or just everyone in general?

Comment: Well yes, sedentary jobs but definitely not a sedentary lifestyle.

Comment: I have seen much info over the last few months to validate that prolonged sitting tightens the psoas muscles which tightens hip flexors and quads and leads me to believe that my hypothesis is correct. I will continue investigating before posting a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I did not have weak quads but that my abs were not doing enough work and this was placing more stress on my left quad initially which became injured and placed more stress on my right quad subsequently.

The injury was occurring from my **teeth**. I have realised, from consultation with a qualified physiotherapist and wearing a mouth guard, that I tend to bite or grind my teeth throughout the day and hold my breath. This closes my airways. Over a long period of time this has negative effects on my abs as my lungs are not expanding to their potential and in turn not keeping my abs activated. My abdominal muscles, particularly on my right side due to there being more internal organs on that side of the body, were shuting off.

Wearing the mouthguard, and undertaking daily short exercises to work my abs particularly the left side of my body, has reactivated my left lower abs and my left glute muscles. This has reduced the workload on my quads, because my glutes and abs are doing more of the work, and has returned myself to the condition I was in before

Comment: It is a good thing to try and share your knowledge Q&A style and answer your own question, **but** it should still be done in line with health SE policies. Here [references are strongly encouraged](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) and answers without them are at risk of being deleted. Furthermore, the link between wearing the mouthguard  and preventing quad injury is very far fetched and it needs reliable references to prove it.

Comment: Yeah I had this is mind when answering as I usually like to give references but I was so happy to have found a solution. I will ask my physiotherapist, I couldn't find anything online with a quick search. Also, readers should note that the exercises I was given were the main reason for the solution to my imbalance while the mouthguard was important.